# How to check if there is something stored in an array element or not

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to make a condition, to see, if there is something than an empty array

```
char data[12][100];
int i;
int sum = 12;
for (i = 0; i <= sum; i++)
{
   printf("Hello \n");
   printf("%d \n", sizeof(data[sum][0]));
   if(data[sum][0] != NULL){
      return 0;
   // code fillin data[][] + some printfs
}
```

I have tried this code ... but it gets stuck in that condition (sizeof is telling me, that its = 1, but I feel like that's the size of that 1 specific element ) so any idea, how can I check if its empty or not ?

also, here is output I get:

```
Hello 
1
```

expected :

```
Hello 
1 
// Some other printfs
```

Comment: sizeof() is a compile-time operation, not runtime.  It will always return 1 in your scenario.

Comment: Well I assumed that :D the point is that I want to check if that array part is empty or no

Comment: @StyleZ an array cannot be empty. It can be uninitialized (which you can't check for) or it can have values in it.

Comment: depending on how you use the array you can chose a certain value to be considered the "empty" value for your application. For `char` you can chose the `\0` for instance. Be mindful that you do need to initialize the array before reading from it

Comment: You can't determine whether any given character is 'empty' or not; it always contains a value, which may or may not be known and determinate.  Note that on many systems, `if (data[sum][0] != NULL)` will generate a warning about comparing a pointer with an integer.  Use `'\0'` for the null byte.

Comment: So in other words, i should first set the value to something and then check if the value is still the same ?

Comment: Where is the closing brace for your `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays always contain values so you have to know the value/values you want present in your array in order to work with which in this situation count as the "empty" values that you're talking about.